# Qualcomm atheros QCA61x4a is not recognized

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04

I have a Lenovo Y720 with Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A, and since I started to use Linux (I'm a beginner) I haven't been able to connect with my house wifi. Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize the device.

How can I fix this?

```
1: ideapad_wlan:
Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: yes 
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth 
Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: yes 
3: phy0: Wireless LAN 
Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: no 
6: hci0: Bluetooth 
Soft blocked: yes 
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `rfkill list`

Comment: rfkill list result:
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Answer (score 1):

Check `mokutil --sb-state` if it shows Secure Boot is enabled reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings, then in terminal do

```
sudo apt install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/ideapad-laptop.git
sudo dkms add ./ideapad-laptop
sudo dkms install ideapad-laptop/1.0
```

Reboot